# Duplicate file in Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm trying to duplicate a file from a bucket to another but I can't seam to see the new file on the destination bucket.

I'm getting **no errors** at all...

**Request:**

[image]

**Response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CopyObjectResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <LastModified>2012-04-08T11:26:36.000Z</LastModified
    <ETag>&quot;a5f9084078981b64737b57dbf1735fcf&quot;</ETag>
</CopyObjectResult>
```

But I keep checking the *Last Modified Date* on S3 and I can't find any information about this new file, either I can access it directly

> http://jk-v20.s3.amazonaws.com/PublicFiles/3ff28e21-4801-47c6-a6d0-e370706d303f_Content_Favicon.ico

What am I doing wrong?

---

Method:

```
public void DuplicateFileInCloud(string original, string destination)
{
    try
    {
        CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest();

        if (original.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            // could be from other bucket, URL will show all data
            // example: http://jk-v30.s3.amazonaws.com/PredefinedFiles/Favicons/002.ico
            string bucket = getBucketNameFromUrl(original), // jk-v30
                    key = getKeyFromUrl(original);          // PredefinedFiles/Favicons/002.ico

            request.WithSourceBucket(bucket);
            request.WithSourceKey(key);
        }
        else
        {
            // same bucket: copy/paste operation
            request.WithSourceBucket(this.bucketName);
            request.WithSourceKey(original);
        }

        request.WithDestinationBucket(this.bucketName);
        request.WithDestinationKey(destination);
        request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;

        using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(this.accessKey, this.secretAccessKey))
        {
            S3Response response = client.CopyObject(request);
            response.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
    {
        throw s3Exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you didn't checked official help, it may worth it, there is complete example: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jk-v20.s3.amazonaws.com//PublicFiles/3ff28e21-4801-47c6-a6d0-e370706d303f_Content_Favicon.ico

Is where the file is. (Note double slash. // ..) If you hit this Url you see the ico file. So its something to do with the leading slash, which may be added automatically by your toolset.

Comment: In other words the destination parameter is being passed with a slash character at the front.

Comment: thanks, this was driving me nuts for some time, and I started to thing everything else and missed the simplest thing... This is when we really do appreciate to have StackOverflow :o)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the request (with headers), captured with something like fiddler?

The [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html) indicate that the source path should start with a slash (i.e., fully qualified), have you tried that?

```
x-amz-copy-source: /source_bucket/sourceObject
```

Maybe the framework does that for you, but your destination has a leading slash so maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Code looks correct, I am using something similar in my working application.

It might be helpful to enable server access logging on your s3 buckets to understand what is happening behind the scenes - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html.